# Is it possible to set Allocation Unit Size with GParted when formating an external hard drive?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I want to format and set a single partition in an external hard drive with GParted (Ubuntu 12.04) and would like to set the Allocation Unit Size. I don't see any options to do this with GParted. Is there a way to set AUS in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, none of the GUI tools can do that. Partitioning works perfectly with those tools also standard formatting work like a charm but for really advanced options you only have the commandline tools.

Standard on Linux is **mk2fs** for building (formatting) ext2/3/4 filesystems.
The amount of options is quite large, including options for **blocksize** (AUS), journalling, inodesize, presets, superblocks, trim/discard etc. etc. etc.

Use the command **mkntfs** for building (formatting) NTFS filesystem.
Again, a lot of options are possible here.
Type **man mkntfs** for an explanation how to use it.

Comment: my target is to format an external hard drive in NTFS filesystem, and since it will be used mostly for video files I want to set the unit size (blocksize) to be at least 4096KB (at the moment is 512/512 bytes). Could you please type the command I should use or give me a link to sources I can look for it there? Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer a bit. I think it is best if you first try to figure it out yourself a bit (good to get yourself some hands on experience) if you can't get it to work after some experimenting you can always show the commandline you used and I will take a look at it. :-) good luck

Comment: you might take look at this http://blog.onetechnical.com/2009/06/09/format-an-ntfs-drive-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for the tip,
I've read the manual at [Ubuntu manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mkntfs.8.html) and executed the following:
`mkntfs -c 65536 /dev/sdc1`
there are few questions that are bugging me:
What are the best practices of formatting NTFS partition - 
I haven't choose fast formatting and it's quite slow (it's running 5min now and it's still on 7%).
I haven't choose compression, should I select it?
And there is a note that `Windows cannot use compression when the cluster size is larger than 4096 bytes` - Will I have any problems with Windows?

Comment: I am not  Windows guru but I'll try to answer :-)  You won't get any benefit from compressing (video is already heavily compressed) a non-quick format can take up to several hours (as described in the article). I cant predict problems (if I could I would be a billionaire ;-) but I think that the best practice is to run windows and do a filesystemcheck after you formatted the disk. You are doing well, no worries :-)