# How to format microSD to FAT with 64bit cluster size

Tags: partitioning, wine

I want to format my SD card for use within a SKY3DS+ Flashcart for the Nintendo 3DS, it needs to be formatted to FAT with a 64kb cluster size. The Disks Utility is not giving me the option to choose cluster size and the recommended DiskWriterV203b4.exe supplied does not run on Wine.

Is there any kind of format utility for Ubuntu 16.04 that will give me this option??

Comment: Also see http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=17030

Comment: 64 bit cluster size does not seem realistic. You mean 64 kB (kilobyte) maybe?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I meant 64 kb cluster size

Comment: 64kb and 64kB are not the same, please make sure if it is 64kb or 64kB. `kb=kilobit`, `kB=kiloByte`

Comment: @ByteCommander What's marked the duplicate doesn't really have a good answer.  I'd say that should be marked the dupe of this.

Comment: @legends2k Fair, reopened it. The linked/related question was [Is it possible to set Allocation Unit Size with GParted when formating an external hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370660)

Answer (score 7):

[`mkfs.fat(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mkfs.fat.8.html) has the options `-s` and `-S` for custom cluster and sector sizes.

> - `-s SECTORS-PER-CLUSTER`
>
>   Specify the number of disk sectors per cluster.  Must be a power of 2, i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, ... 128.
> - `-S LOGICAL-SECTOR-SIZE`
>
>   Specify the number of bytes per logical sector. Must be a power of 2 and greater than or equal to 512, i.e. 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, or 32768.

So the command you want should be something like with the correct device name, 128 clusters per sector and a sectors size of 512byes:

```
mkfs.vfat -s 128 -S 512 /dev/name
```

for this purpose vfat and fat are probably the same although the 3DS might only want to read filesystems from partitions marked as vfat rather than fat. fat is from the msdos era and vfat is from the win95 onwards era.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I'm kind of new at Linux and terminal entry etc. how do I install mkfs.fat? I will need step by step instruction, type this then that style step by step.

Comment: @Amias From `man mkfs.vfat`:
`-S LOGICAL-SECTOR-SIZE Specify the number of bytes per logical sector.  Must be a power of
2  and  greater  than  or equal to 512, i.e. 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, or 32768.`
Your idea is good, but it should be `mkfs.vfat -s 16 -S 4096 /dev/name` (16*4096Byte=64kB),
 other variants are possible to get 64kB. OP added information in comment after you answered. I just see he want 64 kb, that might be different...

Comment: good spot mook765,  i've updated the answer to include it , thanks !

Comment: thats vfat not fat but it should be the same for these purposes.  Given the relative age of the 3DS i'd guess its vfat not normal fat

Comment: @jimmydabosh this probably shouldn't be attempted unless you know a bit more about using the terminal and finding device nodes. There is a high risk you could format the wrong partition.

Comment: oops , good spot @EricDuminil

Comment: BTW, I tested it with Sky3DS+ yesterday. It should be `-s 128 -S 512`, the micro SD card isn't recognized otherwise.

Comment: wow , you just keep on giving :)