# Format FAT32 partition with set "Allocation Unit Size"

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, fat32

Note: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/370701/481256) didn't work for me.

I wish to format a FAT32 partition with set AUS of 32K. I've read the man page `man mkfs.fat`, and the only thing that I can find is

```
-S LOGICAL-SECTOR-SIZE
    Specify the number of bytes per logical sector.  Must be a power of 2 and greater than or equal to 512, i.e. 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, or 32768.
```

I don't know whether this is the "AUS", but I tried it out, and set `-S 32768`. This happened:

```
user@pc:~$ sudo mkfs.fat -S 32768 /dev/sdb1
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Warning: sector size is set to 32768 > 4096, such filesystem will not propably mount
WARNING: Not enough clusters for a 32 bit FAT!
mkfs.fat: Attempting to create a too large filesystem
```

I also tried `sudo mkfs.fat -I -S 32768 /dev/sdb` if that works, and it doesn't. Same error prints out.

Comment: What happens if you try `sudo mkfs.fat -s 32 /dev/sdb1` ?

Answer (score 2):

I needed a 4096 allocation unit size for a Creality 3D printer's firmware update, and to do that I needed to divide 4096 by 512 (the default sector size) to get 8, and run `mkfs.fat -s 8 /dev/mmcblk0p1`.  Note the lowercase `-s`.

Comment: Thank you, my Ender 3 S1 Pro's screen firmware wouldn't update until I did this!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to divide by `512` (the cluster size):

```
mkfs.fat -S $((32768/512)) /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 0):

[`man mkfs.fat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/mkfs.fat.8.html):

```
-s SECTORS-PER-CLUSTER
    Specify the number of disk sectors per cluster.  Must be a power of
    2, i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, ... 128.
```

The allocation unit size is also known as the cluster size.

Comment: Tried that out. I want 32 KB clusters, and 1 sector is 512 bytes. Therefore, I set `-s 64`. But I tried `blockdev --getbsz /dev/sdb1`, and 4096 came out. What does this mean?

Comment: Also did `fsinfo /dev/sdb1` and `st_blksize` is 4096.

Comment: That's going to be the kernel's block size, not the file system's.